# Drupal 7 Views Module - generate field with custom code

Tags: drupal, view, field, drupal-7

In the Views module, if you set 'row style'=fields, you can specify which fields you want displayed. One of my fields is an image type (i.e. I have a content-type that has an image field). As well as displaying the image I want to display the image dimensions and the 'alt' tag. Is there a way of doing this for either of these cases? For example can I add a custom field where I can generate the content with my own PHP or something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible using Views UI, but you can simply create a template for this view and get the informations you need using php inside that template.

Or you can try to use : http://drupal.org/project/views_php (never tried)